# Rails 3 Ubuntu ENV['http_roxy'] is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Why is ENV['http_roxy'] variable empty under Ubuntu but not empty under Windows XP.

Under Windows XP I am using thin server.
Under Ubuntu I am using Nginx server.

Comment: Do you use Apache in both of them?

Comment: Have you looked in config/boot.rb? Is ENV['http_roxy'] set there?

Comment: Max, thank for reply. But id didn't help me too.